# recursive function for Employee Heirarchy (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, recursion, callback

I have data in table in this format

```
emp_id,emp_name,title,supervisor_id,supervisor_name
11,Anant,Business Unit Executive,8,abc
15,Raina,Analysis Manager Senior,11,Anant
16,Kumar,Conversion Manager,11,Anant
18,amit,Analyst Specialist,11,Anant
25,anil,senior engineer,18,amit
35,Pang Pang,senior engineer,25,anil
38,Xiang Xiang,UE engineer,25,anil
```

I will enter supervisor_id and it will return all employee under that then after continue this until we achieve lower level, i want to do this in node and sql server with recursive function.

I want this data to be in hierarchical way like this .

```
var ds ={  'emp_id':11,
        'name': 'Anant',
        'title': 'Business Unit Executive',
        'children': [
          { 'name': 'Raina','emp_id':15, 'title': 'Analysis Manager Senior' },
          { 'name': 'Kumar','emp_id':16, 'title': 'Conversion Manager' },
          { 'name': 'amit', 'emp_id':18, 'title': 'Analyst Specialist',
            'children': [
              { 'name': 'anil','emp_id':25, 'title': 'senior engineer' ,            
                'children': [
                  { 'name': 'Pang Pang','emp_id':35, 'title': 'engineer' },
                  { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'emp_id':38,'title': 'UE engineer' }
                ]
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the which library you are using to request form server so i will sudo code those portions

```
async getEmployeesBySupervisorId(supervidor_id){
const employees = await <get-employees-query> // you may also need to map the results to your {emp_id, name, title} depending on your query library default to [] if no employees are found
return Promise.all(...employees.map(employee=>{
    employee.children = await getEmployeesBySupervisorId(employee.emp_id)
}))
```

}

That will get you an array of employees, with children until no more employees are found, 
While this will work it fires many queries, it may be better for you to leverage sql and your ORM to make this more efficient in the future.